# Workflow to count major versions

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I need to look at the major versions for a document and send an email out when that major version count gets to a certain number.

Is there a way via SharePoint 2013 designer workflow to count major versions of a document?

I can't just compare the lowest major version number with the latest major version number because that's not an accurate indication of the actual count.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With workflows 2013 you can get the version column, split the version to get the "." (example: 2.5) and you get de version.

But you dont need do this. You can create a workflow, this workflow will fired when document is edited, you check if version is your X version, if true: send your e-mail.

Comment: We can't simply say if the version number is 20+, then send an email.  There are instances where the version count starts at 17 and goes up through 32.  We'd still want to avoid sending emails at this point because the major version count is @ 20 yet.

Comment: By default in SharePoint versions start at 1.0
Is there any change in this regard?

Comment: @DiegoHillesheim - how do you get the item Version in a Workflow? I can not see a way to do this from the Current Item -- only by hardcoding a link to a specific Document Library and then querying on that, which is not portable.